# can't workout why getting a type error on __init__

Tags: python, class, smartsheet-api

Hope someone can help me...

Have the following:

smartsheet_test.py

```
from pfcms.content import Content

def main():
    ss = Content()
    ss.smartsheet()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

content.py

```
import smartsheet as ss
class Content:
    """ PFCMS SmartSheet utilities """
    def __init__(self):
        self.token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

    def smartsheet(self):
         smartsheet = ss.Smartsheet(self.token)
```

however when I execute the code I get:

```
python -d smartsheet_test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "smartsheet_test.py", line 8, in <module>
main()
File "smartsheet_test.py", line 5, in main
ss.smartsheet()
File "/xxxxx/pfcms/pfcms/content.py",     line 10, in smartsheet
smartsheet = ss.Smartsheet(self.token)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

is `self` being passed into `ss.Smartsheet(self.token)` somehow, all I can see is that I'm passing the argument `self.token`. My knowledge of Python isn't too deep at this point. Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Alex

Comment: content should be a class, not a file... File does not work with __init__. 
One keyword, that mentioned in the error is `self`.

Comment: "*My knowledge of Python isn't too deep at this point.*" - May I suggest that you stop whatever you are doing and work through [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/)? The knowledge you gain will be far more valuable than the time it takes.

Comment: Also, please review [ask] and especially [mcve]. It is clear that your error message was not generated by the code you've entered. Please shorten your original program to the smallest **complete** program that illustrates your question. Please *copy-paste* that short program in its entirety into your question. PS. An exception to the *copy-paste* rule is that you should replace your account credentials, as you have done above.

Comment: Are you sure, that the constructor for `ss.Smartsheet` accepts a parameter?

Comment: @Robᵩ Simplified code

Comment: @Matthias SmartSheet doc: `SMARTSHEET_ACCESS_TOKEN. If you prefer, you may alternatively pass your Smartsheet Access Token to the instantiation of the Smartsheet object like this: smartsheet = smartsheet.Smartsheet('INSERT_YOUR_TOKEN_HERE')`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because if the documentation reads as you say, then this is an issue you need to take up with the developers via a bug report.

Comment: Thanks, @Alex2134, for the update. Is it possible that you have a local file named `smartsheet.py`, perhaps in the same directory where `smartsheet_test.py` lives? If so, please rename or delete that file, along with all `.pyc` files in that directory and re-run your test.

Comment: @Robᵩ Great catch many thanks. I have an old file in there named smartsheet.pyc. Wow spent about 3 hours on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have (or had) a file called `smartsheet.py` in your current working directory. Delete or rename that file, and delete any related `.pyc` file.

Comment: Apologies I did have this in place the class declaration, just missed it out of my code! Edited in now